# How to configure/connect Zendesk frpm Microsoft copilot for escalation?

Tags: zendesk, escalation, microsoft-copilot

I am working on Microsoft Copilot and would like to connect to Zendesk for escalation. I am trying to do it with customer engagement hub, but there is nothing which help me to do the configuration.
Zendesk option is there in the list but I don't find any instructions to follow for connection.
Can someone please help me to understand what needs to be done to escalate or hand off to the Zendesk live agent

I did try to update the Escalate Topic and add the transfer conversation node in it and added the bot iframe in Zendesk Iframe side bar but its not working. As there is link missing between copilot and Zendesk.